# C++ casting float changes number wrongly

Tags: c++

I have got this calculation in my c++ code
`r=(float)736778906400/100` now obviously the answer should be `7367789064`,but compiler returns `7367789056` what is the problem

Comment: Read about the numerical capacity of a float or just use a double.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh okay thanks

Comment: Mumble mumble c-style mumble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
(float)736778906400/100
```

You first cast `736778906400` to a `float` and then divide by `100`, so you will get multiple rounding errors:

1. `736778906400` is not exactly representable by a 32-bits `float` (which is the most likely `float` size);
2. the final result of `float(736778906400) / 100` is not exactly representable by a 32-bits `float`.

#### Representation of 736778906400 as a `float`

Assuming you are on a standard architecture that uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) 32-bits floating point values for `float` you can only represent exact integer values between `-16777216` and `+16777216` (`2^24`, since 32-bits IEEE floating point have a mantissa of 23 bits).

`736778906400` falls inside the range `[2^39 + 1, 2^40]`, so the number will be rounded to the nearest multiple of `2^(39 - 23) = 2^16 = 65536`, which is `736778911744`. You can check this by doing the following:

```
float x = 736778906400;
```

A [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a mantissa of 52 bits, so it can exactly stores integer values between `-2^53` and `2^53`, so you can easily store `736778906400` **exactly** inside a `double .

See, e.g.,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for more details on the rounding values of float.

#### Division of 736778911744 by 100

`100` is exactly representable by a `float`, so no rounding error here. The problem comes from the rounding at the end of the division algorithm for IEEE 754.

`736778911744 / 100` is exactly `7367789117.44`, which is within the range `[2^32 + 1, 2^33]`, so the value is rounded to the nearest multiple of `2^(32 - 23) = 2^9 = 512`, which is `14390213 * 512 = 7367789056`.

---

Comment: @MrLister You are right, I have updated the answer.